# How to pass properties via CompositeEvent

Tags: masstransit, saga, automatonymous

I've got some events in state machine

```
public Event<FirstCompletedEvent>? FirstCompletedEvent { get; set; }
public record FirstCompletedEvent(Guid PaymentKey, string PaymentDetails) : IQueueMessage;

public Event<SecondCompletedEvent>? SecondCompletedEvent { get; set; }
public Event<ThirdCompletedEvent>? ThirdCompletedEvent { get; set; }
```

`AllCompletedEvent` fires when all of 3 arrived.

```
CompositeEvent(() => AllCompletedEvent, x => x.AllCompletedEventStatus,
       FirstCompletedEvent,
       SecondCompletedEvent,
       ThirdCompletedEvent);
```

**Question**: is it possible to **pass data from** `FirstCompletedEvent` **into** `AllCompletedEvent` for futher processing. To make something like this:

```
   During(Payout,
       When(AllCompletedEvent)
            .Then(c => DoSomething(c.Data.PaymentDetails)
```

I've tried to save it to state in event handler, but it fired (if fired at all) after When(`AllCompletedEvent`) - absolutely not what I looking for.

```
   When(FirstCompletedEvent)
        .Then(c => c.Instance.PaymentDetails = c.Data.PaymentDetails)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any event data required in subsequent events should be stored in the state instance by that event's specific event handler. A composite event only stores the fact that the event was raised, not the data included in it.

**UPDATE**

Also, you need to define the `CompositeEvent` after:

```cs
When(FirstCompletedEvent)
    .Then(c => c.Instance.PaymentDetails = c.Data.PaymentDetails)
```

So that the composite event fires after the `FirstCompletedEvent`.

Comment: Separate handler for FirstCompletedEvent is not enough. For now I store data in state and trigger one more FirstCompletedInternalEvent. It works, however I hope there is some less complicated solution.

Comment: Updated to explain how the ordering matters.